# How can I save all JavaScript files in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I have a JavaScript web application and I am using Firebug to debug it.

In Firebug's *Script* panel I can see all JS files which the website is using:

[image: JavaScript files listed in Firebug's *Script* panel]

Is there any way to download all these files?

Comment: Use spiderzilla Firefox plugin. check my answer for detailed info

Comment: You should mention what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use [spiderzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spiderzilla/) Based on HTTrack

There are many ways to download the website assets. below are few ways.

1. [wget --page-requisites url](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm)
2. [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/)

**Follow the similar answers.**
https://superuser.com/questions/114769/plugin-for-firefox-to-download-the-entire-webpage-with-css-javascript
[httrack-wget-curl-scrape-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098315/httrack-wget-curl-scrape-fetch) 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/download-all-remote-assets-js-css-into-local-machine-in-a-batch

Answer (score 1):

You can always right-click a single file (in Chrome's or Firefox' DevTools or Firebug) and then click the option to open the file in a new tab, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save it. But there is no way of saving them all at once.